# paired t test to compare means of proportions

Tags: t-test, paired-data

I have 12 subjects.

One Indipendent variable: word learning (2 levels: learned/not_learned)

One Dependent variable: proportion of sound exemplars in the language heard by subjects (proportion because each subject has been exposed to a different amount of language).

I would like to know if the words learned contain a higher proportion of sound exemplars than "not learned words".

I have calculated the **mean** of the proportion of exemplars in learned and not_learned words and I have used a paired t test to compare the two means.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: nope, there are specific tests for proportions (prop.test), but since your sample size is small I'd recommend you to use Fisher exact test instead (also has its problems, but don't worry).